# How to use replaceValues method of Guava Multimap?

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I want to add, remove and replace values in a MultiMap provided by Guava.

I do this currently to add values..

```
static Multimap<Integer, Float> myMultimap;
 myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
 myMultimap.put(1, (float)4.3);
 myMultimap.put(2, (float)4.9);
 myMultimap.put(1, (float)4.7);
 myMultimap.put(1, (float)4.5);
```

Removing values is easier with Guava library.

```
myMultimap.remove(1,(float)4.7);
```

But how can I use the replaceValues method?

I mean this

```
 myMultimap.replaceValues(1, (float)4.3);
```

Say I wanted to replace value 4.3 with a new value 5.99, how should I do that, the method expects some Iterable function and I am not sure as of how to implement it..

This is the error..

> The method replaceValues(Integer, Iterable) in the
>   type Multimap is not applicable for the arguments (int,
>   float)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Multimap.replaceValues`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#replaceValues%28K,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) takes a collection of values that replaces *all* of the existing values for the given key. From the JavaDoc it looks like you need to use `remove` followed by `put`.

If the map is modifiable, you can get a modifiable view on the collection of values mapped to a single key using `get`, but the view returned is a plain `Collection` without an atomic replace method. You can always create your own helper method. Note that this method is not thread-safe.

```
public static <K,V> boolean replaceValue(Multimap<K,V> map, K key, V oldValue, V newValue) {
    if (map.remove(key, oldValue)) {
        map.put(key, newValue);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you, it all makes sense now... Is there any way to replace values in a multi map?

Comment: @mirroredAbstraction - Only all of the values mapped to a key--not one at a time.

Comment: When using a `ListMultimap` or `SetMultimap`, `Multimap#get` returns a `List` or a `Set`, respectively: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap

Answer (score 4):

```
public class guava_main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        Multimap map = HashMultimap.create();
    
        map.put("game", 1);
        map.put("game", 2);
    
        map.put("book", 4);
        map.put("book", 3);
    
        Iterable iter = map.get("book");
        map.replaceValues("game", iter);
    
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}

// result : {book=[4, 3], game=[4, 3]}
```